# ReferenceError: is not defined in node.js with express

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, express, mongoose

I followed this tutorial to write some coordinates to a MongoDB from Android: http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/04/android-login-registration-nodejs-server.html

When I try to connect from the app, I get the following error in the server

```
ReferenceError: coord is not defined
at Object.handle (/root/gpsavior/routes/routes.js:12:5)
at next_layer (/root/gpsavior/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
at Route.dispatch (/root/gpsavior/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
at c (/root/gpsavior/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
at Function.proto.process_params (/root/gpsavior/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
at next (/root/gpsavior/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
at next_layer (/root/gpsavior/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:77:14)
    at next_layer (/root/gpsavior/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:14)
    at Route.dispatch (/root/gpsavior/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at c (/root/gpsavior/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
POST /coord 500 1ms - 842b
```

This is my routes.js (I just put the get to test it and it works)

```
module.exports = function(app) {
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.end("gpsavior");
});
app.get('/coord', function(req, res) {
res.end("olakase");
});
app.post('/coord',function(req,res){
var num = req.body.num
var lat = req.body.lat;
var longi = req.body.longi;
coord.coord(num,lat,longi,function (found) { <---This one is line 12
  console.log(found);
  res.json(found);
});
});
```

and coord.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var user = require('config/models');
exports.coord = function(num,lat,longi,callback) {
var num = num;
var lat = lat;
var longi =longi;
var coord = new user({
num: num,
lat: lat,
longi: longi });
coord.save();
callback({'response':"OK",'res':true});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are missing a `require('coord.js');` in your `routes.js`